# React Native 0.63.2 iOS Build Error with `ld: library not found for -lAppAuth`

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I was trying to build my RN project for iOS and having an error

```
ld: library not found for -lAppAuth
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this? I also tried to open .xcworkspace file but I am not sure if my xcode is opening the correct file. How do you tell if the xcode is opening xcworkspace or xcodeproj file?

I am on Mac Catalina with XCode 11.4.1. RN 0.63.2.

-- Updated --

I found out that there is an extra `-L` in front of `-L....AppAuth` as following. Is this bug related to this?

```
- L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphonesimulator -L -L/Users/aungmt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myanlearn_for_students-asipdyxbdtsgxofrgmvaagrgceyh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26348

Comment: @BloodyMonkey I have a swift file. I cannot use use_framework! in podfile as it will throw error in `pod install` I did pod disintegrate and pod install and clear DerivedData a few times but no luck yet. Have you faced this problem and how did you solve for your issue?

Comment: I meant to say I checked through the comments and most methods  Thanks!

Comment: I found there is an extra -L in the linking script..

Comment: Found a solution ? have the same issue..

Answer (score 4):

Got exactly the same error.

1. Go to Project Build Settings
2. Find "Search Paths"
3. Remove $(inherited) from "Library Search Paths"

[image]

Comment: Tried this. Same "ld: library not found for -lAppAuth" error on build.

Answer (score 1):

Close the xcode and open .xcodeworkspace rather than .xcodeproj file and clean build

Comment: I always open with .xcodeworkspace but the error still persists.

Comment: Please note that the name of the file is `xcworkspace`, not "xcodeworkspace".